# Large Html file to PDF

Tags: python, node.js, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, node-pdfkit

I wanted to convert a large html file(21 Mb excluding photos) to .pdf but I wasn't able to do that

> **Solution in Javascript or python or even a CLI will work**

I tried two methods:

1. using html-node

   ```
   function writeToPdf(htmlpath, pdfpath) {
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(pdfpath);
            const options = { format: "Letter" };
            const html = fs.readFileSync(htmlpath, "utf8");
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                   pdf.create(html, options).toStream(function (err, stream) {
                   stream.pipe(writeStream);
            });
            writeStream.on("error", function (err) {
             console.log(err);
             reject(err);
            });
            resolve({});
          });
     }

   let htmlpath = 'input.html';
   let outpath = 'output.pdf';
   writeToPdf(htmlpath, outpath)
   ```

This works fine for small html file but gets stucked or I don't know how much file has been processed for large html file

2. I used wkhtmltopdf for windows but it got stuck after few time at 50%

Any help will be amazing for me including JavaScript or Python

Comment: What about pandoc?

Comment: is that work with html to pdf or streams because the input is quite big

Comment: I cannot guess in your case, but for me works in a .md to .pdf export via LaTeX in a document of 389 pages of dense text at two columns with a lot of images and tables, so ...

Answer (score 0):

Use pdfmake npm library it is very easy to create pdf in it from all the sources.
It has both client-side and server-side implementation with javascript.

https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/

Use the playground to create input template online.

http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake

Tons of material available online also.
Comment if you need more help.

Comment: I have an input as a html file and convert that into a pdf. It doesn't seem to support this convertion

Comment: Does this link serves your purpose https://restpack.io/blog/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-node-js/ ?